# How to view details of computers connected via network?

Tags: network

In finder, I can connect computers over the network. However, it just displays the computer's name, without any information such as ip address. Using "get info" does not give any details either.

How can I view those details?

EDIT: to be more specific, I am interested to know the IP address and port. At the moment I could not think of anything other than this, but I do want to know about whether the connection is secure and if other people can connect.

Comment: What info do you want, specifically? (Besides IP address)

Comment: @Allan I have edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "and port"? Port numbers are used by application protocols (e.g. SSH uses port 22, HTTP uses 80), they're not attributes of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

> I am interested to know the IP address and port…I do want to know about whether the connection is secure and if other people can connect.

Finder is not the tool for this.

Finder has no ability to scan open ports on remote nodes.  To get the IP, you can use tools like `ping`, `host`, or `dig`. This assumes you or your organization is running a DHCP server that updates records with DHCP leases.  However, you can try pining the host:

```
ping computername
```

Use `host` to query the DNS server:

```
host computername dns-server
```

There are a number of tools that will do port scans.  `nmap` is one of them.  It’s not built into macOS, but it is available vis [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nmap) or [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/nmap/).  To scan all 65,535 TCP ports on a host, you can issue the command:

```
nmap -sT host -p- host
```

Are there GUI tools?  Yes.  [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is a popular tool.  However, whether using command line tools or GUI tools with point-and-click functionality, these tools are complex and require a significant learning curve.

Comment: If the computer is already shown in finder, does the macOS already know its IP address? Do I still need to request the DNS?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on how it found it…Bonjour, NetBIOS, mDNS….  It’s too broad of a question for here and definitely for comments.  Can you narrow it down?  Can you provide details about your network so we can focus our answers?